# Deleting Images in RichEditbox control of Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, richeditbox

I am trying to insert inline images in my richeditbox control of my windowsphone Application using the code below

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation =PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
         openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
         var imagefile=args.Files[0];
         IRandomAccessStream  stream= await imagefile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
         Notebox.Document.Selection.InsertImage(215,152,25,Windows.UI.Text.VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline,imagefile.DisplayName,stream);
```

But the user could only erase the text and not the image by using the backspace(Delete) key . Kindly provide me a solution for this. Or is there any other way/control that I can provide the user to enter text as well as insert images and delete them both when he needs.